# When calling for an array my array names do not print out, rather, a shamble of numbers and letters take their place

Tags: c++

I am new to coding so I've created a little program as practice, however, one issue I'm having is that when I try to cout a specific part of my Array, Instead of the string inside the array, i get numbers and letters as the output.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {

int choice1;
int choice2;

string Champions[6][3][6] = { { "Varus", "Jinx", "Caitlyn", "Kogmaw", 
"Twitch", "Kalista" },
{ "Jax", "Kindred", "Tryndamere" }, 
{"Ekko", "Vladimir", "Veigar", "Cassiopeia", "Anivia", "Fizz"} };

cout << "Pick a number, between 0 and 2: " << endl;

cin >> choice1;

if (choice1 == 1) cout << "Pick a number between 0 and 2:" << endl;

else cout << "Pick a number between 0 and 5:" << endl;

cin >> choice2;

cout << "You chose:" << Champions[choice1][choice2] << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;

}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: You have 3 pairs of `[]` in your declaration, but only 2 when you try to print - that can't give you what you want

Comment: The string data you pass to initialize that array does not match the declared size for it. You have a 3D array (6x3x6) but you only pass in 15 strings (6 + 3 + 6). Are you sure you understand that syntax correctly?

Comment: what are you getting as output?

Comment: Don't use raw arrays in c++. Your `Champions` variable should be declared as `std::array<std::array<std::array<std::string,6>,3>,6> Champions;` (supposed you really want a 3d array).

Comment: @TheDude Close, but I think it's just `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>>` as the internals have different lengths and the fixed length aspect isn't especially relevant here.

Comment: @tadman TBH. I'd write a small wrapper class using a 1 dimensional `std::vector<string>` internally, and handle the variable length of dimensions mapped to indices internally.

Comment: `string [6][3][6]` does not mean "an array with three string arrays of size 6, 3, and 6, respectively". It's an array of arrays of arrays of strings. `Champions[choice1][choice2]` is not a string but an array with six strings.

Comment: @TheDude That sounds like a pretty tidy solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your array should be declared as:

```
std::string Champions[3][6] = { { "Varus", "Jinx", "Caitlyn", "Kogmaw", 
"Twitch", "Kalista" },
{ "Jax", "Kindred", "Tryndamere" }, 
{"Ekko", "Vladimir", "Veigar", "Cassiopeia", "Anivia", "Fizz"} };
```

Answer (score 0):

try change:

```
string Champions[6][3][6] = { { "Varus", "Jinx", "Caitlyn", "Kogmaw", 
"Twitch", "Kalista" },
{ "Jax", "Kindred", "Tryndamere" }, 
{"Ekko", "Vladimir", "Veigar", "Cassiopeia", "Anivia", "Fizz"} };
```

to:

```
string Champions[3][6] = { { "Varus", "Jinx", "Caitlyn", "Kogmaw", 
"Twitch", "Kalista" },
{ "Jax", "Kindred", "Tryndamere" }, 
{"Ekko", "Vladimir", "Veigar", "Cassiopeia", "Anivia", "Fizz"} };
```

Comment: The `[6][3][6]` notation was an attempt to make an array with length 6, 3, and 6 sub-arrays. This is still wildly off base and would benefit from `std::vector`.